# C++ SFML Draw objects outside of while (window.isOpen()) loop

Tags: c++, loops, drawing, draw, sfml

```
int moveDown = 10;
int moveRight = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            xEnemies[j].drawEnemy(window);
            xEnemies[j].setPos(sf::Vector2f(moveRight, moveDown));
            moveRight += 50;
        }
        moveDown += 50;
    }
```

Hello everyone, here I am trying to draw enemies on the screen with a loop and a vector. I want the player to be able to destroy the enemies, however whenever the enemy gets destroyed the enemy just gets redrawn again because it's under the while(isOpen()) loop. So my question is: is there any way to draw objects outside of this loop?

Comment: How about not drawing the destroyed ones?

Answer (score 2):

Stop of thinking of a drawing operation as a one-time action. This does not work like paper, where you draw once and then it's there until you erase it. With a computer, graphics get erased multiple times a second and it's your job to *redraw* them every time that happens. This is how graphic frameworks and modern graphic cards work.

All your drawing *needs* to be in your game loop.

What you need instead is a boolean flag in your enemy class that is set if the enemy is destroyed. If you don't want to, then put an `if` in your loop and don't draw those that are destroyed. Alternatively you could remove the destroyed enemies from your `xEnemies` vector altogether.